# Mongoose / mongodb find stats based on document order

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

This is the current way im getting what rank a user is based on bank.

User schema:

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    username: {type: String},
    password: {type: String},
    salt: { type: String},
    bank: {type: Number, min: 1, max: 9, default: 1},
    cash: {type: Number, min: 0, default: 0},

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);


// remember that mongoose makes the user id itself
```

User query:

```
Users.find({}).sort('bank').then(function (users) {
var y = 1;
   for (var x = 1; x <= users.length; x++) {
     if (userid == users[x-1].userid) {
       return x;
     }
   }
});
```

Means if the userid is in the first looped result, then he is the richest user regarding bank, and will return 1.

**desired output**:
if user is the richest bank, return 1, if 2nd, return 2. 3, etc.
aka the number of result from the query.

if the user is not occuring before for example 19, its #19.

So in what order the spesific user is, is what im trying to get.

The idea is to get what number in the result row an user is.

Is there a easier way to occur this?

Comment: Can you include sample documents from db, and how the result should like at the end?

Comment: @TalhaAwan included.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The schema doesn't have `userid` but you're using that in the loop. Further, you're not creating a filtered array, just `return x;`, which is doing exactly what? And, `sort('bank')` already sorts the result documents based on bank value. You can change the order with `sort('-bank')` if you need.

Comment: It would be far more efficient to periodically loop the data and update with the current "ranking" stored on the user data. In that way the "more frequent" requests simply retrieve the user and the current "ranking" would already be there. So that would be more efficient than looping all results every time user information is requested. There is no "Oracle like" [`ROWNUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) functionality available to MongoDB. Which is essentially the only way the server could handle the request.

Comment: An alternate approach is perform three "fast" queries. 1. Retrieve the current user. 2. Retrieve the total user count 3. Return the count of users "less than" the current "bank" value. The subtraction of the "less than" count to the "total count" gives you the current ranking `n+1`. Of course there is some error in that with frequent data updates, but you either live with that option or rely on a stored ranking on the user. So either approach as mentioned is a lot better than looping the whole collection on every request.